# How to disable and bypass the javascript window open pop up in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code there is a window open function. But when the user click it, it will show pop up blocker. 
How to bypass this issue?

Below is my code, and hope someone can help to modify it.

```
var getPay={
  initPayment:function(encString,action,subService)
  {

  html = '<form action="" name="getMyPayment" target="getMyPayment" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">' + 
         '<input type="hidden" name="q" value="" id="q"> <input type="hidden" name="i" value="OT" id="i">' + 
         '<input type="button" value="Confirm" ng-click="makepayment()" style="display: none;">' + 
         '</form>'; 
  document.getElementById("getPay").innerHTML = html;

  var q = document.getElementById('q');
  var i = document.getElementById('i');
  q.value = encString;
  i.value=subService
  document.getMyPayment.target ="getMyPayment"

  document.getMyPayment.action = action;
  var payPopUp = window.open('', 'getMyPayment', 'width=400,height=350');

  if (payPopUp) {
      var timer = setInterval(function () {
          if (payPopUp.closed) {
              clearInterval(timer);
              window.location = "/paymentRedirect";
          }
      }, 1000);
  }
  document.getMyPayment.submit();
  document.getElementById("getPay").innerHTML = ""; 
  }
}
```

Comment: You're asking how to work around a user's preference to not have popups?

Comment: I think this has been asked and answered.

Comment: Hi, is there any other way that can serve the purpose like popups? 
because if I use window.open it will show pop-up blocker on user browser

Comment: Use in-window modals.

Comment: Hi @wazz, thanks for your replied. May I know where is the solution? I had google it many time, but none solve my issue

Comment: Hi @Bitz, this is for payment site, when user click submit button, it will show a window where there is the login detail for the bank. if i use window modals, how to do it? Please advice

Comment: Actually, my intention was the same as the first comment - that is the answer you will probably find.

Comment: hi @wazz, is there anyway that can modify my code for that purpose?